# WPF: Two Columns in Context Menu Item

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, datatemplate, itemtemplate

I am trying to create a context menu with two columns like this:

[image: Context Menu]

The text of the item is bound the Name property of the item and the shortcut key is bound to the GestureText property. However, the column definitions do not seem to be obeyed and I see this:[image]

My XAML is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenu2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0,2,0.4,-2.2">
        <TextBlock Text="RightClickMe" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding GestureText}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ContextMenu2
{
    public class CMenu
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public string GestureText { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public  ObservableCollection<CMenu> Items { get; set; }= new ObservableCollection<CMenu>
        {
            new CMenu()
            {
                Name = "Press me",
                GestureText =
                    new KeyGesture(Key.Q, ModifierKeys.Control).GetDisplayStringForCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)
            },
            new CMenu()
            {
                Name = "Press me too",
                GestureText =
                    new KeyGesture(Key.R, ModifierKeys.Control).GetDisplayStringForCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)
            }
        };
    }
}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `InputGestureText` in `ItemContainerStyle` to `GestureText`:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="InputGestureText" Value="{Binding GestureText}"/>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

Also note that setting `HorizontalAlighnment` or `HorizontalContentAlignment` is not going to help. Please note this part of the [default style:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                        SharedSizeGroup="Icon" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                        SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

and the margin of the TextBlock in the third column which is `Margin="5,2,2,2"`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but my guess would be that the MenuItems that contain your columns are not taking up the full width themselves (they are probably left aligned). So maybe try changing their alignment using , e.g. something like this:

```
<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create a custom looking `ContextMenu` you need to override the `ControlTemplate` of the `MenuItem` ItemContainer, i.e. define your `Grid` in the `ControlTemplate` instead of this one instead of in the `ItemTemplate` of the ContextMenu:

```
<TextBlock Text="RightClickMe" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Grid Margin="-1">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" SharedSizeGroup="a"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" SharedSizeGroup="b"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                                        <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#FF26A0DA" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3D26A0DA" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                                            <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="#FF212121" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="10"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" 
                                                                      Content="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                               Text="{Binding GestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#FF707070"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#0A000000"/>
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#21000000"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

If you simply want to bind the `InputGestureText` property to your `GestureText` property you should refer to @Ron's answer.